# How to store ImageIcon in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, icons, jbutton

I have a matrix n*n of `JButton`, in a `JPanel`. Currently, I'm setting `ImageIcon` in each `JButton` that change over time. This is not a simple ImageIcon, it's 2 Images that I overlap with this function:

```
public ImageIcon DoubleImage(BufferedImage eau, BufferedImage img){
        // Create a new image.
        finalIcon = new BufferedImage(
            eau.getWidth(), eau.getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); // start transparent

        // Get the graphics object. This is like the canvas you draw on.
        Graphics g = finalIcon.getGraphics();

        // Now we draw the images.
        g.drawImage((Image) eau, 0, 0, null); // start at (0, 0)

        img = resize((BufferedImage) img, eau.getWidth(), eau.getHeight());
        g.drawImage((Image) img, eau.getWidth()/2-img.getHeight()/2, eau.getHeight()/2-img.getWidth()/2, null); // start at (10, 10)


        // Once we're done drawing on the Graphics object, we should
        // call dispose() on it to free up memory.
        g.dispose();

        // Finally, convert to ImageIcon and apply.
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(finalIcon);

        return icon;
    }
```

My problem now is that at each iteration of time, I have to change my icons in my `JButtons`. It implies that I have to redraw the icones while I don't have more than 10 different final images. But it takes too much times (the application lag with a small 10*10 matrix; since the iteration happen every 1 sec, I have to fix this). I had the idea of creating all the Images at the beginning and storing them somewhere, but I don't really know how to perform this? Maybe with an enum? Just in the constructor of my class?

I have to precise that my main class extends `JButton`, and I instantiate n*n of it for my final matrix.

EDIT: code for the function `resize`

```
public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, int newW, int newH) {
        Image tmp = img.getScaledInstance(newW, newH, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g2d = dimg.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(tmp, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.dispose();

        return dimg;
    }
```

EDIT2: code that I execute at each iteration

```
public void iteration(){
        final Vue vue = marreGraphique.lireVue();
        final Presenter presenter = vue.lirePresenter();


        try{ //here I'm just instantiating my BufferedImage 
            eau = ImageIO.read(new File("Icones/mosaique.jpg"));
            if(grenouille){
                img = ImageIO.read(new File(presenter.getGrenouilleImg()));
            }
            else{
                img = ImageIO.read(new File(presenter.getImg(ligne, colonne)));
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e){}

        icon = DoubleImage(eau,img);

        setIcon(icon);

        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    }
```

Comment: are you trying to resize the image? (referring to `resize()`)

Comment: Yes, I edited my post with the code of `resize`

Comment: Yeah, I saw... trying to figure out what's going on...

Comment: You are drawing the image twice

Comment: What do you mean? I'm drawing the two images that I want to overlap in `finalIcon`. I'm also redrawing the image when I'm resizing it, is that what you meant?

Comment: my answer should clarify what I mean. I'm adding in some more helpful things in a few moments.

Comment: What's `Presenter`?

Comment: Basically, this is the intermediate between my View and my Modele. I'm using the pattern Modele View Presenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the images in a static, external class (Lets call it `Testing` for now):

```
public class Testing {
    private static List<ImageIcon> images = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void add(ImageIcon im) {
        images.add(im);
    }

    public static List<ImageIcon> get() {
        return Testing.images;
    }
    public static void clear(){
        images.clear();
    }
...
```

and then:

```
icon = DoubleImage(eau,img);
Testing.add(icon);
setIcon(icon);

...
```

Each time you need to recreate the icons, clear the list with `Testing.clear()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But if I delete `g.drawImage((Image) img, eau.getWidth()/2-img.getHeight()/2, eau.getHeight()/2-img.getWidth()/2, null);`, `img` will not appear (I'm overlapping `img` on `eau`).

Comment: @pioupiou1211 have you tried? because if you have, then it's weird, seeing as how you draw `img` in `resize()`.

Comment: Oh, I know what you mean. In `resize`, I'm resizing `img` because it's too small compare to `eau`. But in `resize`, I'm never drawing `img` in `finalIcon`. EDIT: i tried, and `img` don't appear

Comment: Can you please show the entire code needed to run this? because it's hard to test it like this

Comment: thank you for you help. Then, I have to create all my Images at the beginning and then just pick the one that I want with a factory for exemple? With factory, I mean a simple method that give me the Image that I want with a switch and a String in argument.

Comment: I'll try it out and accept the answer if it works :)